# I can set android:textColor in android application's theme, but I can't set android:text - why?

Tags: android

When I create my own theme in my Android application, I can set default textColor:

```
<style name="MyStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffff00</item>
</style>
```

However, when I try - just for experiment - set default text, it does not work:

```
<style name="MyStyle">
    <item name="android:text">tralala</item>
</style>
```

Why?

Comment: please give me detail when apply your style in xml..

Comment: I don't apply it as style in XML - I set is as a theme in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: By the way, I don't need it for anything useful - I just would like to know how things work and what makes some attributes different then others.

Answer (score 0):

style resource is used to define look and feel of UI , not to define default text. for that use string resources

Answer (score 0):

I think style is used for UI property and re usability,

```
<style name="MyStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/survey_list_item_heading</item>
    </style>
```

If you will use

```
<item name="android:text">tralala</item>
```

Then it wont be reusable by other TextView.
So better define all the Tag except text so that other TextView also.

```
                 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ptr_id_last_updated"
                style="@style/MyStyle"
                android:text="Your Text" />
```

Hope you will take care of these things.
Thanks,